# I cannot raise error in a custom check in discord.py

Tags: python, error-handling, discord.py

I have to raise a custom error in a custom check in my discord bot.

I have this code:

```
class CommandDisabled(commands.CheckFailure):
    pass
def check_enabled(ctx):
    db = firebase.database()
    isEnabled = db.child('Disabled').child(str(ctx.guild.id)).child(ctx.command).get()
    if isEnabled.val() is None:
        return isEnabled.val() is None
    else:
        raise CommandDisabled
        return isEnabled.val() is None

@commands.command(name="seen",aliases=["lastseen","last"])
@commands.check(check_enabled)
async def _seen(self,ctx:commands.Context,user:discord.Member):
    db = firebase.database()
    seen_data = db.child("Last Seen").child(str(user.id)).get()
    if seen_data.val() is None:
        await ctx.send("**I have not seen that user so far.**")
    else:
        time = seen_data.val()["Time"]
        time_seen = datetime.strptime(time, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f")
        final_time = datetime.utcnow()-time_seen
        total_min = round((final_time.total_seconds())/60)
        temp = 0
        while total_min >= 60:
            total_min -= 60
            temp += 1
        minutes = total_min-temp*(60)
        if temp == 0:
            em = discord.Embed(description=f"**`{user.name}` was last seen `{minutes} minutes` ago.**",color=discord.Color.random())
            await ctx.send(embed=em)
        else:
            em = discord.Embed(description=f"**`{user.name}` was last seen more than `{temp} hours` ago.**",color=discord.Color.random())
            await ctx.send(embed=em)
```

Now here i raise CommandDisabled error in my check_enabled function. Then i handle it as follow:

```
@commands.Cog.listener()
async def on_command_error(self,ctx,error):
    if isinstance(error, CommandDisabled):
        em = discord.Embed(description="This command is disabled in your      server. Ask admin to enable it",color=discord.Color.random())
        await ctx.send(embed=em)
```

But it does not work the embed i want to send does not work. The command just stops working but the embed telling that it is disabled is not sent.

This code is inside a cog

Please help me.

Comment: try printing the error inside the error handler

Comment: The error handler does not work idk why but i tried printing yes inside error handler and nothing happened

Comment: Can you include the error handler in your question?

Comment: I included the error handler as you said

Comment: try removing the error handler, and check if it prints CommandDisabled in the terminal, if it doesn't then the check function is broke

Comment: It does not print CommandDIsabled in the terminal but it raises a check failure error. It was working first but stopped working after i added another check when i removed the other check it was still not working

Comment: Oh sorry.......... But the error was only on my pc when i hosted it , it worked fine. idk why